# Why Intellij do not find any Maven dependencies in pom.xml?

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, intellij-idea, pom.xml

I just downloaded Intellij on a laptop and I imported a Maven project and the problem is that Intellij do not found any dependency in pom.xml. For example if I try to import hibernate-core or any other dependency I get the error: Dependency org.hibernate-core... not found. What should I do? Any feedback will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you able to run the command like mvn clean package from command line ?

Comment: Run `mvn install` command. It will download all the dependencies.

Comment: Sometimes intellij idea do not refresh maven dependency on startup. To do so on the right side of idea there is docked panel with `Maven`. Just open it and click `refresh`. Should reload project and you should see difference.

Comment: @Sambit Yes I'm able to run the command from command line

Comment: @Pawel If I try tu run refresh I get an error: Cannot resolve plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5.3 … 11:02 AM Error running 'refresh': Cannot run program "refresh" (in directory "D:\Projects\my-project"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

Answer (score 20):

In case of Intellij Idea, make right click on pom.xml, select maven and then click to reimport. Find below the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Looks like this option was replaced with `Reload project`, which solved the problem for me. Why we have to do this by default is beyond me -- extremely, extremely frustrating.

Comment: Doing the refresh for maven and gradle is unfortunately a way of life in Intellij. 2022 and this still isn't ironed out well.

Comment: Doesn't work with 2022.2.3 IntelliJ is really buggy, bad quality IDE compared to VS Code, Eclipse etc

Answer (score 11):

I solved this issue by running "mvn idea:idea" command.
It resolved all module dependencies and also add it to classpath in intellij.

Comment: can you please explain what that command does?

Comment: Doesn't work with 2022.2.3 IntelliJ, running above command from project directory, it did download many libraries but still I couldn't get rid of basic errors in import. I doubt if project is referring to these downloads or not ?  IntelliJ is really pain in doing these basic operations

Comment: I can confirm on June 2023, it works. Sometimes maven --> reload works, sometimes this is needed.

Comment: It works like a charm on idea 2021.2.3 (community edition) - probably it is needed when adding dependency on third party libraries not common

Comment: Right click `pom.xml`, Maven --> Reload.  Did the trick.  Thanks @nayakasu!

Answer (score 4):

It may also be worth checking which Maven your IDE is using. You can check it in settings:

[image]

We used to have issues with Maven bundled with IntelliJ.

Comment: I helped. I had set up location of my maven directory. When I switched to `Bundled (maven 3)` option then it updated the libraries

Comment: Doesn't work with 2022.2.3 IntelliJ, there is no Maven option seen under Build Tools. Not sure why does IntelliJ keep changing UI each release ? Most bad quality IDE

Answer (score 1):

You could also go to File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Maven -> Repositories and check that the local maven repository is set.

Same for File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Remote Jar Repositories where the remote maven repository should be set (something like https://repo1.maven.org/maven2)

Comment: Not applicable for 2022.2.3 IntelliJ

Answer (score 0):

After "Maven" > "Reload project" an additional "Build" > "Rebuild project" (in IDEA window menu) was necessary to eliminate all "dependency ... not found" error messages in my case.