# CometChat Cannot resolve symbol 'CometChatUserListScreen'

Tags: java, android-studio, uikit, cometchat

I have been following the tutorial for CometChat. It seems some imports are not working. How to I fix?

tutorial site: https://www.cometchat.com/tutorials/how-to-build-an-android-chat-app-in-java

```
public class ContactActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_contact);

        CometChatUserListScreen.setItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener<User>() 
    {
            @Override
            public void OnItemClick(User var, int position) {
                 Intent intent = new 
Intent(ContactsActivity.this,CometChatMessageScreen.class);
                intent.putExtra(StringContract.IntentStrings.UID, var.getUid());
                intent.putExtra(StringContract.IntentStrings.NAME, var.getName());
                intent.putExtra(StringContract.IntentStrings.AVATAR, var.getAvatar());
                intent.putExtra(StringContract.IntentStrings.TYPE, 
CometChatConstants.RECEIVER_TYPE_USER);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            @Override
            public void OnItemLongClick(User var, int position) {
                super.OnItemLongClick(var, position);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

[screen shot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I0TwB.png)

Answer (score 0):

Its a common problem with IDE's, make sure your dependency is on your classpath. Also, see the following links:

[Why Intellij do not find any Maven dependencies in pom.xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57520486/why-intellij-do-not-find-any-maven-dependencies-in-pom-xml)

[In IntelliJ, Maven can't resolve dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62095814/in-intellij-maven-cant-resolve-dependencies)

[Intellij Idea often doesn't resolve Maven Dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65277972/intellij-idea-often-doesnt-resolve-maven-dependency)

[Force Intellij IDEA to reread all maven dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9980869/force-intellij-idea-to-reread-all-maven-dependencies)